# How to upgrade a meteor app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, upgrade

My App created by Meteor is now doing upgrading by Meteor's HCP(Hot Code Push), which means the user will get a new version as soon as he restarts the App, without any information or confirm dialog.

HCP is great, but there are two reasons some users don't want the App be upgraded quietly:

1. New version may have degrades or other risks.
2. Old version is enough for theirs uses.

So I want to know if there is a way, I can show user a new-version-available dialog describing features of the new version, and ask him whether to upgrade or not. When he agreed, use HCP to do the upgrade work or, download the necessary package by writing code if HCP not usable in this occasion.

By the way I have another question related: Why HCP only work on android phone, how to make it work on iOS phone.

Many thanks in advance for answering any one of the two questions, or both.
Thank you.

Comment: Hot Code Push with Meteor **does** work with iOS. If you have trouble with that, feel free to open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> By the way I have another question related: Why HCP only work on android phone, how to make it work on iOS phone.

HCP should work on all platforms in the same way.

To show prompt dialog you have to intercept HCP in `Reload._onMigrate` hook:

```
import { Reload } from 'meteor/reload';

Reload._onMigrate(() => {
  const decision = confirm("New version is available, would you like to upgrade now?")
  return [decision]; // Return [false] to manually handle HCP
});
```

This is a very simple example, you can trigger nice UI/UX element to handle it.

For example we always return `[false]` in `_onMigrate` hook. Show to the user nice pop-up. And if user choose to update now, we trigger next function (*pick options you need*):

```
// Purge and reload cache for AppCache package
window.applicationCache.swapCache();
window.applicationCache.update();

// Drop ServiceWorker cache
window.caches.keys().then((keys) => {
  keys.forEach((name) => {
    window.caches.delete(name);
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error('window.caches.delete', err);
});

// Unregister Service Worker
SWRegistration.unregister();

// Reload the page
if (window.location.hash || window.location.href.endsWith("#")) {
  window.location.reload();
} else {
  window.location.replace(window.location.href);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Reload._onMigrate hook worked well, thank you. but if I choose not to upgrade, it will not ask me again when the app is restarted. How to upgrade if the user changed mind after having chosen "no" at the first time?

Comment: @vdonkey you may set a timeout to ask about upgrade repeatedly or add a button to upgrade, somewhere in UI.

Comment: After failed many times I found where is the question: during I use the App, I altered the server, the App will ask me whether to upgrade or not immediately. that is fine. But even if I choose not to upgrade, after the App is restarted, it is still upgraded  to the new version quietly. That is not what I want. I want to keep the user using the old version if he chose "no" when "upgrade now?" dialog showed until he click an upgrade button somewhere in the App intentionally.

Comment: Well, it can be done using Service Worker and/or Appcache package. But it's a big topic for separate question. I can answer it if you will start separate thread.

Comment: I have created another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135240/how-to-suppress-the-auto-upgrade-mechanism-of-meteor-app   Thanks a lot for your help