# How to suppress the auto upgrade mechanism of Meteor App

Tags: meteor, auto-update

I want that when my Meteor App detected server changes, it will show a confirm dialog to the user whether to update or not. If the user choose "no", the App will not update itself even it is restarted. Then the user will have to press an update button on the settings page for example if he wants to update in the future.

Now I know how to popup the confirm dialog ([How to upgrade a meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695207/how-to-upgrade-a-meteor-app)), but still having no idea about suppressing the auto-update mechanism (HCP) when the App is restarted.